# How to export data from table to csv file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I'm trying to export from a data table into a CSV file. Here is my whole function. It downloads a file, but it shows the whole code for the table and not separating any of the data out. When I say whole code I mean everything within 'table /table'

```
function displayDataTable(index){
$("#pageOverlay").empty();
    html = "<div id='volumeChartDiv'><h4>Data Table</h4><table id='dataTable' class='table table-bordered table-striped dataTable' role='grid'><thead><tr role='row'><th>header1</th><th>header2</th><th>header3</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>cell1-1</td><td>cell1-2</td><td>cell1-3</td></tr><tr><td>bell2-1</td><td>bell2-2</td><td>bell2-3</td></tr><tr><td>fell3-1</td><td>fell3-2</td><td>fell3-3</td></tr></tbody></table><input type='button' value='Close' onclick='closeOverlay()'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='button' id='exportDataTable' value='Export Table'></div>";
  $("#pageOverlay").html(html);
// export data function    
  $("#exportDataTable").click(function (e) {
      window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('.dataTable').html());
      e.preventDefault();
});
   openOverlay();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more? not clear about _shows the whole code for the table and not separating any of the data out_ Are you filtering dataTable?

Comment: So within the csv file, on row one cell one it has all of the table code from <table></table>. I'm not sure how to filter all ofthat out. I tried looking around on here first and didn't seem to find anything that worked.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

CSV format cannot accept `$('.dataTable').html()` as `.html()` is not a structured data, it's not even data, just a silly hmtl.

You have to get data from your table, make a string representing CSV format, and download it, As you don't show your table data structure here's working demo below

```js
$('#export').click(function() {
  var titles = [];
  var data = [];

  /*
   * Get the table headers, this will be CSV headers
   * The count of headers will be CSV string separator
   */
  $('.dataTable th').each(function() {
    titles.push($(this).text());
  });

  /*
   * Get the actual data, this will contain all the data, in 1 array
   */
  $('.dataTable td').each(function() {
    data.push($(this).text());
  });
  
  /*
   * Convert our data to CSV string
   */
  var CSVString = prepCSVRow(titles, titles.length, '');
  CSVString = prepCSVRow(data, titles.length, CSVString);

  /*
   * Make CSV downloadable
   */
  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", CSVString]);
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  downloadLink.href = url;
  downloadLink.download = "data.csv";

  /*
   * Actually download CSV
   */
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click();
  document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
});

   /*
* Convert data array to CSV string
* @param arr {Array} - the actual data
* @param columnCount {Number} - the amount to split the data into columns
* @param initial {String} - initial string to append to CSV string
* return {String} - ready CSV string
*/
function prepCSVRow(arr, columnCount, initial) {
  var row = ''; // this will hold data
  var delimeter = ','; // data slice separator, in excel it's `;`, in usual CSv it's `,`
  var newLine = '\r\n'; // newline separator for CSV row

  /*
   * Convert [1,2,3,4] into [[1,2], [3,4]] while count is 2
   * @param _arr {Array} - the actual array to split
   * @param _count {Number} - the amount to split
   * return {Array} - splitted array
   */
  function splitArray(_arr, _count) {
    var splitted = [];
    var result = [];
    _arr.forEach(function(item, idx) {
      if ((idx + 1) % _count === 0) {
        splitted.push(item);
        result.push(splitted);
        splitted = [];
      } else {
        splitted.push(item);
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
  var plainArr = splitArray(arr, columnCount);
  // don't know how to explain this
  // you just have to like follow the code
  // and you understand, it's pretty simple
  // it converts `['a', 'b', 'c']` to `a,b,c` string
  plainArr.forEach(function(arrItem) {
    arrItem.forEach(function(item, idx) {
      row += item + ((idx + 1) === arrItem.length ? '' : delimeter);
    });
    row += newLine;
  });
  return initial + row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="export">export</button>

<table class="dataTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

<sup>If you find any bugs, comment below, i'll fix them</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  In my case, some of my cells contained commas.  I changed "  $('.dataTable td').each(function() {
    data.push($(this).text());" to "  $('#dataPrimary table td').each(function() {
 var cellData = $(this).text();
 //var cleanData = escape(cellData);
 var cleanData = cellData.replace(/,/g, "");
    data.push(cleanData);
  });" and it works as expected.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried converting the code to coffeescript using `js2.coffee` but i get a `Reference error, arr not defined`

Comment: This is working fine but not working with comma(,), sinlge quote('), and double quote("")

Comment: This works great, although I had to trim the titles + data to give a valid CSV file
titles.push($(this).text().trim());
data.push($(this).text().trim());

Comment: Just used this for a client site and works flawlessly, thanks

Answer (score 3):

An small improvement over Medet answer, assuming that you headers are in tr, all this code does is get all the columns and rows push that in plain array and exports to csv.

```
$('#export').click(function() {
  
  var titles = [];
  var data = [];
  
        $('.table tr').each(function() {
                data.push($(this));
            });

    csv_data = []

  data.forEach(function(item,index){
    td = item[0].children
    for(i=0;i<td.length;i++){
     
      csv_data.push(td[i].innerText)
    }
   
    csv_data.push('\r\n')
  })

  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", csv_data]);
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  downloadLink.href = url;
  downloadLink.download = "minicrawl.csv";
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click();
  document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
  
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If the data's not too complicated, then you can get by without jQuery:

```js
const csvContents = [].map.call(document.getElementById('dataTable').rows,
        tr => [].map.call(tr.cells, td => td.textContent).join(',')
    ).join('\n'))
```

and then download the file as with the other answers.

This won't work if the data's a bit more complicated (eg, has commas in the data), but in that case you should probably use a csv library in the first place.